# How can I reduce the depth of the cutout for my kitchen sink?

Tags: faucet, installation, kitchen-sink

I have a composite "Silgranit" drop-in sink that has developed cracks, and I want to replace it with a stainless steel sink.

The original has an outer size of 20½x31 and I want to install the same dimension but in stainless.

The issue I have is that the hole in the laminate countertop opening was made for a composite (19½ x 30 red outline) but a stainless needs an extra 2 to 3 in the back for the faucet and taps to hold on to, an opening of about 17x30 (blue outline).

I don't want to start over with a new countertop.

**Question: What is a reliable way to install a piece of material to allow the fixtures to be mounted?**

[image: install guide]

[image: cutout]

Comment: What do you  mean "*for the faucet and taps to hold on to.*" ?  On the most common sinks The faucet and taps should be fixed to holes in the stainless sink.  It is not clear what exactly your problem is, Is the hole the correct size for the new sink? Does your new sink not have holes for the faucet, meaning is the faucet mounted through the counter itself ? Photos of both sinks may clear things up.

Comment: As @AlaskaMan said, not clear about the sizing - normally the hole for a stainless steel sink has to be big enough for the faucets/etc. mounted to the sink. But the big question, whether more has to be cut or something patched in: **What is your countertop surface?** Formica (and other laminates) is quite different from granite (and other stone) which is different from Corian (and similar materials).

Comment: Photos from above and below would be fantastic. You'll need to support a filler block and we need to see the whole hole situation.

Comment: Our undermount SS sink does not have holes for the faucet. The faucet is mounted in a hole in the soapstone countertop.

Comment: What type and thickness of material is the "laminate" layed upon? As @isherwood said, you should be able to span the gap from below with wood, and attach a filler-block on that of the necessary thickness to give you the right height to support the stainless sink deck/ledge.

Comment: Most stainless sinks are actually self-supporting. The faucet doesn't need to bear on the counter top. Do you have reason to believe otherwise with your sink?

Comment: I have never seen a stainless steel sink/faucet installed like the one in the illustration in the first photo you posted (in the USA). There is usually no counter under the faucet holes in the steel.